# Gunrt start ," Fatal error: spawn EACCES"

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

[root@iZ25q0v42mrZ myapps]# grunt server
Running "server" task

> > The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.

Running "serve:undefined" (serve) task

Running "clean:server" (clean) task

> > 1 path cleaned.

Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task

Running "wiredep:test" (wiredep) task

Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task

```
Running "copy:styles" (copy) task
Copied 1 file

Done, without errors.


Execution Time (2016-01-23 17:20:04 UTC)
loading tasks               236ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 88%
loading grunt-contrib-copy   18ms  ▇▇▇ 7%
copy:styles                  13ms  ▇▇ 5%
Total 267ms
```

Running "postcss:server" (postcss) task

> > 1 processed stylesheet created.

Running "connect:livereload" (connect) task
Started connect web server on http://localhost:9090
Fatal error: spawn EACCES

Execution Time (2016-01-23 17:20:03 UTC)
loading tasks                  221ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 16%
wiredep:app                    163ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 12%
wiredep:test                    16ms  ▇▇ 1%
concurrent:server              582ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 43%
loading grunt-postcss           54ms  ▇▇▇▇▇ 4%
postcss:server                 148ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 11%
loading grunt-contrib-connect  104ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 8%
connect:livereload              28ms  ▇▇▇ 2%
Total 1.3s

Who can help me to look at. Thanks

Comment: The above is all log!

Answer (score 13):

You don't have permission to make changes.

1. Go to project folder.
2. Open terminal in project folder & execute following command .

   ```
   sudo chmod -R a+rwx ./
   ```